# How to put -dontwarn or -ignorewarning command in Proguard GUI?

Tags: android, jar, proguard

I recently have trouble to use the proguad GUI to obfuscation my .jar file creating from the android studio. I want to obfuscation all the private method name by using proguard GUI. I have using the android-24/android.jar as a library. But I still get the 1 warning. [Warning picture from Proguard GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvQ7j.png) Like this picture. I don't know how to put -dontwarn or -ignorewarning command inside the proguard GUI. I also have search other people's question. [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936187/how-to-avoid-warnings-in-proguard-gui)
[question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263296/how-to-obfuscate-jar-file-using-proguard-gui-application). But nobody answer. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And here is a video from youtube. This might be help. But he got no warning in it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MeQosb-pP6A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure out by myself. I have find there is an option that I can select inside the Proguard GUI. Please check the picture. [The ignore warning option in the proguard GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WRkZ.png). If that take you a lot of time. My apologize. This method is good for obfuscation the class name or method name inside the .jar file.

Comment: Good answer, worked for me! But I recommend you to place the picture inside the answer, and not as a external link which can broke in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can save configuration using the "Save configuration..." button on the Process tab. Open it in notepad, add -dontwarn line, save and reload it using "Load configuration..." button on Proguard tab.

In your case line can be

```
-dontwarn com.esielect.serialport.usbserial.SerialInputStream
```

This solution is better than completely ignore all the warnings. If you ignore all warnings you can miss some important one and get issues in runtime